# How to get the value of a hidden input field in a Django view?

Tags: django, forms, hidden

I have a form which has a hidden field like below:

```
    <form id = "subscribe" form method = 'POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea id = "first_name" type = "text" name = "first_name" rows="3"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" id="page_url" name="page_url" value="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">
            <button type="submit" value = "Subscribe" id = "email_submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I am trying to get the value of the hidden field. Specifically, what I want is the URL of the current webpage. My view function looks like this:

```
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.POST.get('first_name')
        pageurl = request.POST.get('page_url')
        print('page url', pageurl)

    return HttpResponse("/")
```

As you can see I am trying to get the URL via `request.POST.get('page_url')` but all I am getting is a `None` value. I need to get the value of `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ object.get_absolute_url }}` instead.

Comment: Couldn't you use the `HTTP_REFERER` header from the `request.META object`?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: value is unquoted... (what is the generated html from your template?)

Comment: ps: your input is `type="text"` by default, you need to explicitly set it to `type="hidden"` to make a hidden input (/field).

Comment: The value must be  : `value="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"` instead of `value={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ object.get_absolute_url }}`. **Note the quote around the  django like value**.

Comment: @thebjorn setting quotes around the value of `value` doesn't change anything. Also, I already set the type to hidden and that doesn't change anything either. Even when I use a literal string in value as in `<input type="hidden" id="page_url" name="page_url" value="waka">`I still get None printed out from the view function.

Comment: Have you considered that you may be posting to the wrong url (Or writing the code for the checking in the wrong view)? (I don't see any `action` attribute on your form and it seems you post to that view from multiple different pages)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am successfully getting the value of the `firstname` property of the same form from the same view. Also, this is not a problem with the URL. Even if I replace `value="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"` with `value="any string"` I still get None instead of getting `any string`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, your guess is right - that form is on multiple pages and the form action URL is handled by some Javascript code.

Comment: @multigoodverse in that case you are lacking a [mre]. The code you show should be (just) enough to _reproduce_ the problem you face. From my guess you should also share the relevant url patterns and the javascript that actually does the posting.

Comment: what does your browser's devtools say is posted?